# How to use both laravel custom request with default request

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get multiple image for my products and i following this [tutorial](http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4) the issue i have if i use tutorial way I'll receive error because saving product from image uploader control `$product = Product::create($request->all());` but i have my own validation for products in `ProductController` and no want to use this validator in `ImageController`

So I decided to add

```
foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
  $filename = $photo->store('images');
  Image::create([
 'product_id' => $product->id,
 'filename' => $filename
 ]);
}
```

in my `ProductController` after `$product->save();` in order to get product id and changed `$request->photos` to `UploadRequest::photos` here it is:

```
foreach (UploadRequest::photos as $photo) {
          $filename = $photo->store('images');
          Image::create([
              'product_id' => $product->id,
              'name' => $filename
          ]);
      }
```

Then I added my request top of my `ProductController`

```
use App\Http\Requests\UploadRequest;
```

The error I get now is:

> Undefined class constant 'photos'

Here are my complete codes:

## ProductController store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      //Validating title and body field
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'title'=>'required|max:225',
          'slug' =>'required|max:255|unique:products',
          'sku' =>'nullable|max:255',
          'stock' =>'nullable|max:255',
          'user_id' =>'required|numeric',
          'short_description' => 'nullable|max:1000',
          'description' => 'required|max:100000',
          'subcategory_id' => 'required|numeric',
          'brand_id' => 'nullable|numeric',
          'price' => 'required|numeric',
          'status_id' => 'nullable|integer',
          'weight' => 'nullable|max:255',
          'length' => 'nullable|max:255',
          'height' => 'nullable|max:255',
          'width' => 'nullable|max:255',
          'arrivialin' => 'nullable|max:255',
          'meta_description' => 'nullable|max:255',
          'meta_keywords' => 'nullable|max:255',
          'publish' => 'required',
        ));

      $product = new Product;

      $product->title = $request->input('title');
      $product->slug = $request->input('slug');
      $product->sku = $request->input('sku');
      $product->stock = $request->input('stock');
      $product->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
      $product->description = $request->input('description');
      $product->short_description = $request->input('short_description');
      $product->subcategory_id = $request->input('subcategory_id');
      $product->brand_id = $request->input('brand_id');
      $product->status_id = $request->input('status_id');
      $product->price = $request->input('price');
      $product->weight = $request->input('weight');
      $product->length = $request->input('length');
      $product->height = $request->input('height');
      $product->width = $request->input('width');
      $product->arrivialin = $request->input('arrivialin');
      $product->meta_description = $request->input('meta_description');
      $product->meta_keywords = $request->input('meta_keywords');
      $product->publish = $request->input('publish');

      $product->save();

      $product->submores()->sync($request->submores, false);
      $product->suboptions()->sync($request->suboptions, false);


      foreach (UploadRequest::photos as $photo) {
          $filename = $photo->store('images');
          Image::create([
              'product_id' => $product->id,
              'name' => $filename
          ]);
      }



      //Display a successful message upon save
      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Product, '. $product->title.' created');
      return redirect()->route('products.index');
    }
```

## UPLOAD REQUEST

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UploadRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required'
        ];
        $photos = count($this->input('photos'));
        foreach(range(0, $photos) as $index) {
            $rules['photos.' . $index] = 'image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|max:2000';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

## routes

```
Route::resource('/products', 'ProductController');
  Route::get('/upload', 'ImageController@uploadForm');
  Route::post('/upload', 'ProductController@store')->name('imageuploader');
```

## UPLOAD FORM

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    Product name:
    <br />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" />
    <br /><br />
    Product photos (can attach more than one):
    <br />
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="photos[]" multiple />
    <br /><br />
</form>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: `$request->photos` ?

Comment: Put `Route::post('/upload', 'ProductController@store')->name('imageuploader');` before `resource`.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `UploadRequest` should passed as parameter in the controller method.So your store method should be like:

```
// ProductController.php
public function store(UploadRequest $request) {...}
```

And then you should move validation rules in `ProductController` to `UploadRequest` rules. If you need different rules combination to `ImageController` than you should create another `FormRequest` class and pass it as parameter in your controller method.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I get that i should use `UploadRequest $request` but what my issue is, is if i use `UploadRequest` then what about my product validation?

Comment: is that right to i move my products validation to images custom request? that make sense? (if i underestand you right)

Comment: Yes, you should move it. So validation for product fields will executed too.

Comment: then what about these parts?  `$product = new Product;` , `$product->title = $request->input('title');` ...... `$product->save(); $product->submores()->sync($request->submores, false); $product->suboptions()->sync($request->suboptions, false);`  ??

Comment: Your custom `UploadRequest` will only modify the validation rules and the validation process. All the attributes from the `$request` will still exist, because actually it's extended from `FormRequest`  class. And `FormRequest` is extended from `Request` class.

Comment: there:    `public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'title'=>'required|max:225',
          'slug' =>'required|max:255|unique:products', ///.......
        ];` i have this now but i get error for my category_id and other parametrs that need integer id, what about them?

Comment: also i changed my product save form route to `imageuploader` which now comes from `ImageController` method

Comment: Make sure the posted data value is `numeric`.  As I said, if you want different combination of validation rules just create another `FormRequest` class, and then modify it to your needs.